# Exception: Access Not Configured - BigQuery with Google Apps Scripts after the API update

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery

After the API update - http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.sg/2013/11/code-updates-required-for-apps-script.html, I did the update inside my code.

But I raise an exception : *Exception: Access Not Configured*

I authorized the apps script to use BigQuery and the script worked well before the API update

```
var projectNumber='XXXXXXX';
var sql = 'a sql query';
var export_table = 'export_table';
var queryResults;

var j = BigQuery.newJob();
jr = BigQuery.newJobReference();
jr.setProjectId(projectNumber);
j.setJobReference(jr);
jc = BigQuery.newJobConfiguration();
jcq = BigQuery.newJobConfigurationQuery();
jcq.setQuery(sql);     

t = BigQuery.newTableReference();
t.setDatasetId("export");
t.setTableId(export_table);
t.setProjectId(projectNumber);

jcq.setDestinationTable(t);
jcq.setWriteDisposition("WRITE_TRUNCATE");
jc.setQuery(jcq);
j.setConfiguration(jc);

try {
    jobs = BigQuery.Jobs;
    var resource = {
      query: j,
      timeoutMs: 1000
     };
    BigQuery.Jobs.query(resource,projectNumber );

 } catch (err) {
    Logger.log(err);
    return;
 }
```

Thanks you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your script and go to resources. Verify that BigQuery is enabled.

Then click on the link in the text below: "These services must also be enabled in the Google Developers Console". This should open the console window, where you can enable BQ for your project.

Also, see: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced

Answer (score 0):

I Think This is simple.  The variable "var jr ='' " was never declared.